# How to Access the State of the reducer in other reducer in reat redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have login page component where i have a state which is boolean called isUserAuthenticated, when i'm clicking on the login button which checks for the userslist wheather the user exists or not. users list is in signupreducer, how can i access the users list in loginreducer and return the isUserAuthenticated flag from it.

**LoginPage Component**

```
export const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        isUserAuthenticated: state.reducer.isAuthenticated.isUserAuthenticated,
        users: state.SignupReducer.users
    }
}

export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        checkLogin: (credentials) => dispatch({ type: 'CHECK_LOGIN', credentials })
    }
};

LoginPage = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginPage);

export default LoginPage;
```

**Login Reducer**

```
const initialStateAuth = {
    isUserAuthenticated: false
};

export const isAuthenticated = (state = initialStateAuth, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'CHECK_LOGIN':
            return Object.assign({}, state, { isUserAuthenticated: checkLogin(state, action) })
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

**Here actually i want to check the user in** 
  singupReducer.users how can i access here....

```
const checkLogin = (state, action) => {
    let isExist = false;
    signupReducer.users.map((each) => {
        if (each.userName === action.credentials.username && each.password === action.credentials.password) {
            isExist = true;
        }
    });
    return state.isUserAuthenticated = false;

}
```

Comment: It seems that you have spelling issues. Sometimes you use  `singupReducer` or `SignupReducer`.

Comment: @DamienGold what ever but i used at only one place and this is not actual i just mentioned "signupReducer" . my question is how can i access other reducer state in specific reducer. thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're using `combineReducers` to set up your state tree. You'll need to write a custom combination function that passes the state you need (from signup) to the login reducer.

There's an example of how to do this in the redux docs: http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/BeyondCombineReducers.html#sharing-data-between-slice-reducers

Answer (score 0):

There's another way, if you don't want to share data between reducers. To accomplish this you use `getState` and include what you need from state in the action you are sending to the reducer which needs it. Here is an example: [Alternative to sharing data between slice reducers](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/BeyondCombineReducers.html#sharing-data-between-slice-reducers)

```
function someSpecialActionCreator() {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        const state = getState();
        const dataFromB = selectImportantDataFromB(state);

        dispatch({
            type : "SOME_SPECIAL_ACTION",
            payload : {
                dataFromB
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any way to do this without writing any custom functions

Comment: Without writing ANY custom functions? No :( You will at a minimum need to  `mapDispatchToProps`, `connect` your component, have `actionCreators`, and a `reducer` to handle the state update..

Answer (score 0):

I did Like this i'm able to access now and it is working, anybody suggest me is that a correct way of doing.

```
export const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        isUserAuthenticated: state.reducer.isAuthenticated.isUserAuthenticated,
        users: state.SignupReducer.users
    }
}
```

Here i'm selected the other reducer state in mapStateToProps then after i'm preparing a class in my click event like this

```
onLogin = () => {
        var credentials = {
            username: this.userName,
            password: this.password
        }
        var loginFormData ={
            credentials:credentials,
            users:this.props.users
        }
        this.props.checkLogin(loginFormData);
    }
```

Finally i'm dispatching my action with credentilas of login form and state of other reducer

```
export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        checkLogin: (loginFormData) => dispatch({ type: 'CHECK_LOGIN', loginFormData })
    }
};
```